# Unable to update gradle dependency for a library

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

This is what i originally had in my build.gradle file.

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.9.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

The library [Material Dialog](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs#gradle-dependency) has been updated so i am trying to reflect the same in my gradle file.The library says i should add it like this.

```
    dependencies {
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

So i tried this but it refuses to rebuild the project when i try this,with an error saying "failed to resolve:com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0"

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: I had the same kind of problem for another library, since the project is on github you can try to import it by downloading it as a zip file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be like this

**App build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

**Project build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: So do i need to add this as well as the dependency file in the other place or can i choose either of them?

Comment: you need to add this, because the library is on that repository

Comment: There is a build.gradle on the root of your project, put that there

Comment: So i removed the compile thing from the other file and added this line and now android studio cannot recognize any of the code belonging to the library and is giving me tons of errors.

Comment: you need **both** of them, don't remove the compile thing

Comment: Tried that too,same error as the first time,it cannot resolve the library.

Comment: Can you please include your project build.gradle in your question

Comment: worked now,it was a mistake on my part,i was adding the maven line under the wrong brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while building [Material-Dialogs][1].

In my case I had to have the same level of Build Tools version as that of the compileSdkVersion. For more info, visit [Android ProgressDialog position issue and do we have Android's ProgressDialog from platform or support library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813640/android-progressdialog-position-issue-and-do-we-have-androids-progressdialog-fr) answer.

**I had (mismatching compile SDK and build tool versions):**

```
 android {    
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    ...[your configuration]
}
```

**which I changed to**

```
android {    
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    ...[your configuration]
}
```